# Why is Flowfile Being Cloned?

Tags: apache-nifi

I was wondering why some processors are cloning the flow file before routing it to next processor.

For example, `QueryDatabaseTable` processor always clones the flow file before passing it to the `ContentAvrotoORC` processor.

Why is there a need to clone the Flowfile ?

[image: Example NiFi Flow]

[image: Event List]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the clone event represents the fact that the same flow is being transferred to two different destinations (`LogMessage` and `ConvertAvroToORC`). So there is one flow file created by `QueryDatabaseTable`, then when the framework sees that success goes two places, it has to clone the flow file.

Comment: okay, hope creating the flow like this will not affect performance much..